# I want to add multi-language support for my modularly implemented project

Tags: android, kotlin, modular

I want to add multi-language support for my modularly implemented project. What is the best way or method you suggest to do this? General in one module)
Please help me.

Comment: This will help you with multi-language support - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages .
Create Strings.xml as per country and use Locale to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have a resource module to can add any resources in that module. This module enables you to change resources one time when you need.

Answer (score -2):

you can make multi strings resources file for each language you want to support
you have the original strings file in res/values/strings
for example, if you want to add Arabic language support
so follow these steps :
1-right click on the values file and click on
new/values Resources directory
2- make the same name (strings) and add the local qualifiers and choose the language  and region
just like this image
[image]

3- copy all your strings from the English strings file and pest them in the new one and edit the translation

now your app will use the language that is set in the device system if it was Arabic then will use the Arabic strings file
and so on for the English

chick this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages)

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Comment: Hello my friend
My problem is not just multilingualism.
My problem is to make the program multilingual, which has several modules, and the main question is to consider a separate string file for each module and create a string file centrally in one module.